# Как правильно заменить глагол с отрицанием?

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно заменить словосочетание с отрицательной частицей (не опаздывать) на словосочетание (быть вовремя или во времени)?

Comment: Если вы изучаете русский как иностранный, то подобные вопросы лучше задавать на другом ресурсе. https://russian.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Первая из предложенных версий правильная:

не опаздывать = быть вовремя

Answer (score 0):

"Не опаздывать" означает "*приходить* или *делать* что-либо **вовремя**", **своевременно**, **успевать** (сделать что-либо, добраться куда-либо). Выражение же "*быть* (где-либо) *вовремя*" употребляется сравнительно редко, поскольку понятие "вовремя" предполагает совершение *результативного* действия к определённому *моменту* времени. С глаголом *быть* лучше сочетается выражение "в нужное время", в котором время может иметь *протяжённый* смысл (как и действие глагола "быть").